# Check Web Application Services is ready

Tags: java, asp.net

I have a couple of Http methods like Get and Post methods Exposed in my application which host in the JBoss.
One of them need to restart JBoss application itself. Others need to make sure the Application is ready for using . All of them are Http Methods. Sometimes the application in boss would be restarted in my application as I called the restart Http method. But My problem is I don't know the application whether is ready to be called other methods, By the way,the client is a .net application .Can anyone give me a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can I just use the Socket Connect the host and port to test whether it is ready ?

Comment: Can someone give me some comments about my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a webservice method "AmIAvailable" which will only return "success" or "True". Call this webservice method. In case u receive a output, then the webservice is available and you can make a call to all methods.

If not, (for ex, you may receive "Service Unavailable" exception), then webservice is not yet available to reach.